# How to request Domain-wide Delegation through a consent screen, on G Suite

Tags: google-api, google-oauth, google-authentication, google-workspace

I need to have access to Calendar information from a company's **G Suite** accounts, to synchronize data with the company system through  a API.

When I need to provide access to my own data, there is a fairly [simple way](https://developers.google.com/calendar/auth) to do it. Using Oauth2, through a login window the user allows the API to access the requested data.

But in the **G Suite** documentation, the [path indicated](https://ctrlq.org/code/20371-service-account-domain-wide-delegation) when involving the administrator and company data, involves the administrator accessing admin.google.com, go to the security-related session, and manually register my API, listing the scopes that he wants to grant me access.

To make a parallel, in **Microsoft Graph** [there is a way to request consent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-service) from the domain administrator, where only a `user consent` / `admin consent` screen is displayed using Oauth2.

I wonder if there is a way to get this type of access in **G Suite** without requiring the end user to take such complicated steps to make my API work properly.

---

**UPDATE:**
This question was originally posted in 2019, does anyone aware if something was changes since then?

Comment: Domain wide delegation is done thru service account credentials which then impersonate another user. No consent screen is required. If instead you want to a user to authorize your application, just use the normal Google OAuth flow. If you clarify your question I can help better. You can also search my account for answers that I previously wrote about G Suite Domain Wide Delegation, OAuth, etc.

Comment: @JohnHanley I need admin G Suite to authorize my app to access the data of the other users of the same domain / company. Without the need to request permission each one individually. In a user-friendly way

Comment: Your comment does not help me understand what your goal is. The solution is in the details. For example, define what your App is, where it runs, are you using three-legged OAuth. You are leaving the important stuff out. If you are trying to create an App that runs, for example, on an iPhone and tries to access everyone's personal data, you are going to have a big problem getting Google to approve it. A formal audit will probably be requested and that is something like $75K+. If your application runs on a server and you are using G Suite Domain Wide Delegation, then you have different options.

Comment: @JohnHanleyThis is a web app. The admin G Suite will log in, and free access for my application to read and write users' Calendar data, to synchronize with company system data. It is a solution that should work for several companies, so I can not ask each one to generate a private key and configure the permissions for me.

Comment: the closest I've found so far, was the option where the administrator accesses the configuration and registers the "Client Id" of my application, along with the scopes https://ctrlq.org/code/20371-service-account-domain-wide-delegation

Comment: I would like to find a form that is closer to that existing in Microsoft Graph https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-service

Comment: The closest you will get is G Suite Domain Wide Delegation for Google services.

Comment: @JohnHanley Maybe I did not choose a correct term to use in the question. But I'm looking to a user-friendly way of getting this

Comment: If you can help me fix the title of the question since "Domain wide delegation" does not describe what I'm looking for, I'd be grateful then

Comment: If delegation does not fit your design, there is no other solution that I am aware of for Google services. You can either use delegation or a user will need to approve your app.

Comment: @JohnHanley i want to use delegation, but in a way less depends on the user(admin) who will access the application. Through the security settings there are many details that depend on the admin set up

Comment: What security settings?

Comment: this @JohnHanley https://ctrlq.org/wp/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/api-client-access.png

Comment: Those settings do not apply to G Suite Domain Wide Delegation. Those settings apply to each user authorizing your application.

Comment: Did you find your answer? We're looking for the same. We have a service account, but instead of asking every customer's admin to manually setup domain wide delegation, we want to do that via a permissions prompt. Something like "Do you give domain wide delegation consent for the following scopes..."

Comment: @NielsFilter at that time wasn't an easy way to delegate permissions on g-suite.
I find a way with many steps (basically this https://elextensions.com/knowledge-base/set-up-google-oauth-g-suite-configure-google-oauth-credentials-wsdesk/ )

Comment: This is a 2 years old question is anyone aware if something was changes since then and we have something which is closer to Microsoft Graph now?

Comment: @HaimRaman unfortunately I did not return to work with microsoft graph after 2019

Comment: @HaimRaman I start a bounty, let's see if anyone can help

Comment: Thank you for that :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use the [Marketplace SDK](https://developers.google.com/workspace/marketplace/enable-configure-sdk) for this. This allows you to publish an application to the Google Workspace Marketplace where [company admins can choose to install it for their domain](https://support.google.com/a/answer/172482?hl=en).

There are a couple things to keep in mind:

- There's an expectation that your application will have some sort of user facing presence (e.g. add-on, link to web app, etc).
- Google will review your app before publishing. Since you're not using Gmail or Drive scopes (for these, Google requires a 3rd party security review), this process should not be too difficult. But plan for it to take some time, and follow the [best practices](https://developers.google.com/workspace/marketplace/about-app-review) so it's done right the first time.

You also mentioned synchronizing calendars. If that means mainly reading, no problem, but if you're writing (a lot at once), be mindful of [calendar use limits](https://support.google.com/a/answer/2905486?hl=en). These are per user and for all activity by that user (not just your app).