# How to programmatically request domain-wide delegation for Google Calendar API?

Tags: google-api, google-oauth, google-calendar-api, google-workspace, service-accounts

I've spent a few hours now looking through the docs + reading other SO posts, and it's still not clear to me how to simply **request domain-wide credentials for Google Calendar API** (*for other domains; not my own*).

Our current web app kicks off an OAuth flow to request Calendar API credentials for a single user; however, there doesn't seem to be a simple way like this to request credentials for an entire domain. It seems that acquiring domain-level access requires the admin to manually set up a service account and then pass that information over (https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/delegation) which is incredibly cumbersome.

With Microsoft's Calendar API, this is a very straightforward process where you simply specify "Application Permissions" and then the OAuth flow must be completed by an Admin to get the expected set of access and refresh tokens. For GSuite, I can find no such equivalent...

To clarify based on some comments, I'm trying to figure out if GSuite has anything equivalent to what Microsoft Graph offers as described here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-service

The closest I've seen requires publishing to the Google Apps Marketplace; however, the documentation here seems to be quite lacking and it's unclear how things like redirect_uri for handing over credentials to the backend server are handled.

If I've missed any documentation and someone can just point me in the right direction then that would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: 1) Your question is confusing. What do you have and what have your tried? Domain Wide Delegation uses a service account to impersonate a user. The process is very simple and Google published examples in most languages. There are also answers here on SO. Edit your question with details to clarify your problem. 2) Since you mention **other domains**, that means other Workspace accounts. The other domain will need to set up the delegation and provide you with a service account. I would **never** provide a third-party vendor/application with a service account with delegation enabled.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @JohnHanley thanks for the reply. My question is very similar to another one you commented on [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54790619/how-to-request-domain-wide-delegation-through-a-consent-screen-on-g-suite).

To clarify your comment about never providing a third-party application delegated permissions, does this mean you would also never install something at Admin level from the Google Workspace Marketplace? It seems that this would potentially provide an application the ability to operate on any user account which is effectively what I'm after here...

Comment: I am not qualified to make security comments on Marketplace due to a lack of experience and knowledge with that service. You must still trust the developer/vendor that wrote the Marketplace app so my hesitancy would still apply. It would depend on what type of data is being made available and the cost of a security issue. Today, it is simply too easy to share sensitive data with third-party apps unknowingly. Every day the news mentions another vendor security breach. Some of those announcements shock me with their potential impact on companies.

Comment: Thanks, John. Makes total sense and agree it's important to be thoughtful in this space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best documentation for how to set up domain wide delegation to a service account is -> [Perform Google Workspace Domain-Wide Delegation of Authority](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/delegation)

> request domain-wide credentials for Google Calendar API (for other domains; not my own).

You can not. The admin of the google workspace domain sets up domain wide delegation for service accounts owned by the domain.

> there doesn't seem to be a simple way like this to request credentials for an entire domain.

Service account authorization is very different from Oauth2 authorization.  Service account authorization is is intended for backend systems that need access to data without requesting user permission.

Oauth2 allows you to grant authorization on a per user basis.  The user must grant an application access to their data by accepting the consent screen.

There is no oauth2 flow that would grant your application to all the users on a workspace domain.   TBH I think thats a good thing.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm familiar with that walkthrough but looking for something more programmatic like what Microsoft Graph offers as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-service)

Comment: Microsoft and Google are two different companies.    They have different products and different security allowances for their products .    Maybe my answer was not clear.   What you want to do can **NOT** be done with google workspace currently.  Each user must authorize your app.     Apps developed by a company for their personal workspace domain used to allow for full domain verification but that feature no longer works, since the change in JavaScript sign-in system.    It never worked for third party apps.

Comment: Ok thank you! A straightforward "nope" is super helpful in this case.

Comment: @LindaLawton-DaImTo I get that this is how google has implemented it, but the user AND developer experience for doing this as an admin is horrible. 

You're essentially asking administrators from a domain (may or may not be technical people) to copy paste some instructions from the app they are using without knowing what permissions they are most likely giving away.

The average joe utilising these apps have no clue what they should be doing and just want to make the connection to google.

Is there any channel to discuss this feedback?

Answer (score 0):

1. Only super administrators can configure domain-wide delegation, this is done in the Google Workspace Admin console
2. When you enable domain-wide delegation for a service account, basically you are giving it the permission to impersonate any user within your domain
3. If you need to make Calendar requests on behalf your users, in your app you will need to implement impersonation, that way you will use the service account with wide-domain delegation to make the requests on behalf your users
4. Here you can find the documentation explaining how to set up wide-domain delegation and an example for making the API calls implementing impersonation https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account#authorizingrequests

Comment: Thanks for the reply; I'm familiar with the manual creation of the service account file but looking for something more programmatic here like how in Microsoft Graph you can ask for "Application Level" / admin permissions which can be obtained via a standard OAuth flow by an Admin. With an access token from that flow, you can then perform operations for any specified user in the domain (essentially what the GSuite service principal here provides, but without all the additional steps required by the admin).